# How to center a textarea using CSS?

Tags: html, css, textarea, center

Forgive me for asking such a simple question, I'm new to both HTML and CSS.
Is there an easy way to center a textarea? I figured I'd just try using

```
textarea{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

but it (obviously?) didn't work.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The margins won't affect the textarea because it is not a block level element, but you can make it display block if you like:

```
textarea {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image: before and after]

By default, textareas are `display: inline`, which is why you can put them side-by-side easily, and why the `text-align: center` answers work too.

The textarea can also be centered by putting it inside a [flexbox container](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) like this:

```
<style>
    div.justified {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="justified">
    <textarea>Textarea</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I'm using now, do you know if there's anything bad about it (as it sounds too easy to be true/good ;-) )?

Comment: Nope, I don't know of any downsides.

Comment: One downside is when textarea is resized, (by dragging resize-handle), it is no longer adjusted to center. (At least on Chrome).

Answer (score 11):

Set `text-align` of the element's parent to `center`, like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
div { text-align: center; }
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ujzLt/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I have already assigned some colors and other things to the div element though, how do I get one which only has text-align:center;?

Comment: @Chris -- just add `text-align:center;` to your current `<div>`'s css declaration then. :-)

Comment: You can add all styling to the same div (color, font-family, text-align,...) or isn't this what you mean?

Comment: I actually wanted to remove the styles from the div so they wouldn't apply to the textarea, but perhaps that isn't needed (thought it would form a box with background color and padding, like my div does)?

Comment: They do not apply to the textarea, you can leave them as they are.

Answer (score 2):

add `display: block;` to your textarea styles

Comment: Hey that did the trick, combined with the styles I already had, like you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>#container {width:100%; text-align:center;}</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<textarea name="mytextarea" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you wrap your textarea with a div, give it width and then you align it with `text-align:center;`

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)! However, like I explained above, I have already made my div prettier, how do I get back to a default one with just the text align?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  It works for me here in 2020:

```
textarea {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```